# Rendering (rounding?) issue in Chrome when zooming

Tags: css, google-chrome

Here's a simple setup with two `div`s next to each other in a parent container which has a border while the two children have different background colors. There's also a [codepen here](https://codepen.io/airblader/pen/ZEOpNqG):

```css
.tag {
  /* Also happens with .1rem */
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50px;
}

.key {
  background: black;
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50px;
}

.value {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="tag">
  <div class="key"></div> 
  <div class="value"></div>
</div>
```

On Google Chrome when zooming in I get rendering issues like this (note the white line between the border and black div on the top/left edges):

[image]

I've tried various things like flexbox, using `rem` for the border width etc., but at best it changes at which zoom level and on which edge the issue appears. I assume this is some kind of sub-pixel rounding issue, but I wonder if there's *any* way to fix this.

Comment: Hope you found a solution by now but using `box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 1px black` to avoid any pixel rounding between parent and child seems to work for me.

Comment: @tomcek112 That does look a bit better, but it draws past the bounding box on higher zooms, a little bit anyway. And no, I haven't found any other answers so far.